# My Item grid item is not spanning multiple rows

Tags: html, css

I want my main to take space of three grid-items but it doesn't seem to work. It is working for columns but not for rows.
code:

```css
.feed {
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: 20vw 20vw 20vw 20vw;
  grid-template-rows: 12vw;
}

.feed-column {
  background-color: white;
  height: 15vw;
  width: 18vw;
}

.main {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="feed">
  <div class="feed-column main"></div>
  <div class="feed-column"></div>
  <div class="feed-column"></div>
  <div class="feed-column"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add sample design you are looking forward to achieve?

Comment: You have fixed the height of main. What do you actually want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

You gave them a combined class of "feed", which has a grid template of 4 columns. In my experience, it is best to deal with them as separate components even though they are under a single div. You can try to separate them like below

```
      <div>
        <div class="main"></div>
        <div class="feed">
          <div class="feed-column"></div>
          <div class="feed-column"></div>
          <div class="feed-column"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

So you can give the main whatever style you want without making the rest of the columns dependent on it.